# Can the Linux kernel be compiled on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: kernel, osx, gui, linux-kernel, laptop

I have a Macbook Pro and I want to build the [Linux Kernel](http://www.kernel.org/). Can I build 3.3.6 on my Mac? How?

Comment: If you have gcc, binutils and make, yes... it should be possible.

Comment: @diegows how could I install binutils? I have gcc and make.

Comment: You can compile from source on your own or use a nice package manager like Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)

Comment: @Ben How do I compile from source? From what website do I get the source

Comment: @Coder404 GNU binutils: http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

Comment: Can I ask why? (Just curious)

Comment: @JosephKern ask why about what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an excellent site for newbies about Linux Kernel, it's called [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/).

You'll find on it an excellent [tutorial](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) explaining how you can get the source, configure and compile the Linux Kernel.

But, beware, it's not an easy task. There's really many many many options to look at and to understand before you can start to build a decent one. It can be a little more complicated on Mac OS X, since you won't have any *oldconfig* ready to recompile.

BTW, there's also an [interesting book](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) made by Greg Kroah-Hartman.

Comment: don't worry about oldconfig, there is an alternative:  defconfig.